# Why is PollingIntervalTest test_getlastupdate_no_change failing with the error “could not convert string to float” in Sonos Self-Test Suite

Tags: sonos

I've run the Sonos Self-Test Suite [available here](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=docs) and everything passes except for this one error, and I'm not sure why:

```
Test case: PollingIntervalTest test_getlastupdate_no_change
Instance messages: could not convert string to float

...more output...
2016-02-23 09:43:40,834 [STOP] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.PollingIntervalTest - could not convert string to float:
2016-02-23 09:43:40,834 [STOP] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.PollingIntervalTest - 1212827 PollingIntervalTest test_getlastupdate_no_change
2016-02-23 09:43:40,836 [DEBUG] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.PollingIntervalTest - [('../../sonos-1.1.0.dev_r208947-py2.7.egg/sonos/workflow/fixture.py', 2494, '_run_test_iteration', 'testMethod()'), ('/Users/rob/Dropbox/dev/projects/composed/sonos_downloads/sonos-selftest/smapi/content_workflow/getlastupdate.py', 40, 'test_getlastupdate_no_change', 'poll_interval = self.smapiservice.get_polling_interval()'), ('../../sonos-1.1.0.dev_r208947-py2.7.egg/sonos/smapi/smapiservice.py', 374, 'get_polling_interval', "pollinterval = self.config.getfloat('Polling Interval', 'interval')")]
2016-02-23 09:43:40,836 [INFO] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.PollingIntervalTest - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
2016-02-23 09:43:40,836 [INFO] SONOS.sonos.workflow.result - End *test case* test_getlastupdate_no_change at Tuesday, February 23, 2016 09:43 AM
```

Here's what my service returns:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
  <soap:Body>
    <tns:getLastUpdateResponse>
      <getLastUpdateResult>
        <catalog>2016-02-18 11:52:30</catalog>
        <favorites>Rob-2016-02-18 12:01:00</favorites>
        <pollInterval>30</pollInterval>
     </getLastUpdateResult>
   </tns:getLastUpdateResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It seems virtually identical to the [sample response in the Sonos API docs](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/87). You can see that pollInterval has no type information specified in the SOAP XML, so I'm struggling to see how this error is due to something I'm doing.

Am I doing something wrong, or could this be a problem with the test suite itself?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be an issue with the selftest's handling of special characters, specifically ":", within token values. If possible, try returning simply an integer as specified in the sample response to see if this resolves the issue.